# Delivery Notification Failure issue

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

My requirement is based on the messagetype field in the XML schema I have to route the incoming message to two (one as primary and another one as secondary) FTP locations and send an email notification to client saying the message has been transmitted to two ftp folders.

If there is any failure in sending the message to primary ftp location, then the message has to be transmitted to secondary ftp location and failure email has to be trigger to client.

Design which I have implemented is inside decision shape I am checking the message type and inside scope I have created 2 send ports and expression shape to send email notification. For handling exception for first logical send port I have set the `Delivery Notification=transmitted` and in catch block I am sending failure notification. This logic is working fine in case of success but in case of failure I am getting both success and failure email notifications when I try to test.

Can someone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a separate scope with an exception block around each send shape.  In your exception blocks set a a different variable (default true) to say if that send has not succeeded (false).  After both of the send scopes, have a decision shape that looks at these variable to see if both succeeded, only send 1 succeeded or only 2 succeeded and send the email based on that.

Comment: I tried the above logic.created 2 scope with one scope contains send port 1 and exception block and inside exception block i have created expression shape and  i have set variable1=true.In another scope i have send port 2.in decision shape i am checking if variable 1= true and if true sending error email and if false sending success email.But when i try to test in both success and failure case, only failure email is getting triggered.anything i missed here?

Comment: @Chitra You need both a variable1 and a variable2 and check them both after both exception blocks. If variable1 & variable2 (both true) then success.  If !variable1 & varbiable2 then first send failed, if variable1 & !variable2 then 2 failed. Else both failed.   Are you trying to send two emails, or just one email with the status of both ports?

Comment: i am trying to send 2 emails one with success email and another with failure email

Comment: @Chitra Then just check after each scope and send it there.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.Will try and let you know the result.